# Angular Material variables in scss

Tags: angular, sass

I try to define global scss variables related to material colors.

```
:root {
  --primary-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-primary, default);
  --text: mat.get-theme-color($my-theme, foreground, text);
}
```

While debugging it looks good, I get:

```
DEBUG: #3f51b5
DEBUG: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)
```

but in components, when I try to use it like `color: var(--primary-color)` it has no effect at all. When assigning some primitive value like `--primary-color: red` it works fine, so the connection between global `_theme.scss` and my component looks good. Any ideas?

version:

```
"@angular/material": "^17.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **#{...}** syntax to interpolate **mat.get-xxx** value.

Make these changes:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($my-primary, default)};
  ...
 }
```